# Using javascript to automatically create input-group from Bootstrap 3

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to use javascript to automatically modify my input boxes to

```
<div class="input-group">
**<input type="text" class="form-control " placeholder="Text input">**
<span class="input-group-addon">*</span>
</div>
```

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/BEC7N/

The **bold** line is the line that already exists.

Below is my javascript attempt

```
$('[data-val-required]').prepend(' <div class="input-group">');
$('[data-val-required]').append(' <span class="input-group-addon">*</span></div>');
```

But it doesn't work. Any ideas? Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your code to this:

```
$('[data-val-required]').wrap(' <div class="input-group"></div>');
$('[data-val-required]').after(' <span class="input-group-addon">*</span>');
$('[data-val-required]').after(' <span class="required-indicator">*</span>');
```

[**Working Example**](http://jsfiddle.net/BEC7N/50/)

Comment: This does work. Thank you :) but my extra * is not attached to the original input box. Any ideas? http://jsfiddle.net/BEC7N/48/

Comment: Just run your `$('[data-val-required]').after(' <span class="required-indicator">*</span>');` **after** the other two lines. If this is what you mean?

Comment: I've updated my comment with a jsfiddle illustrating the problem.

Comment: As well you need to add the class `form-control` to your `input` if you want to use bootstrap styles.

Comment: I solved my design issues by putting the * before the textbox instead of after. Thank you both.

Answer (score 2):

Use `.wrap()`

```
$('[data-val-required]').wrap('<div class="input-group" />');
$('[data-val-required]').after(' <span class="input-group-addon required-indicator">*</span>');
```

Comment: This does work. Thank you :) but my extra * is not attached to the original input box. Any ideas? http://jsfiddle.net/BEC7N/48/

Comment: Can you post desired output?

Comment: I solved my design issues by putting the * before the textbox instead of after. Thank you both.